# How to invoke firefox browser installed in other driver than C drive using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, invoke, selenium-firefoxdriver

How to invoke Firefox browser installed in other driver than "C" drive using Selenium?

I have installed Firefox in D drive rather than C driver. Is there a way to invoke browser using selenium in this context?

EDIT 1:

Am not concerned with location of driver . I am only concerned with installation location of browser.Hope you understand

Comment: you need to access geckodriver for that, not firefox driver

Comment: are u unable to access it

Comment: You haven't mentioned the `Selenium Binding` you are using `Java`, `Python`, `C#`, `JavaScript`, `Ruby` or `Perl`

Comment: Am aware that we need to use gecko to launch firefox. what if the location of browser installed is not in C drive
please refer Edit1

Answer (score 0):

Try `FirefoxBinary` for achieve it code for java

```
File pathBinary = new File("Your path of firefox driver");
FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathBinary);
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();       
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxBinary, firefoxProfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

For C#

Create a folder called Drivers. Add all the drivers you want, chromedriver, gecko, IE, phantom whatever. Set each to "copy always" so it goes to your bin directory.

Then create the GetBasePath method and call it accordingly. I would also create a switch statement and call whatever driver you want to use.

```
    ex:
    _webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(Path.Combine(GetBasePath, @"Drivers\"));
```

or

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
 options.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", false);
 _webDriver = new ChromeDriver(Path.Combine(GetBasePath, @"Drivers\"), options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));



        public static string GetBasePath
    {
        get
        {
            var basePath =
                Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            return basePath;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox must install on default place like ->(c:/program files/mozilla firefox ) If firefox is installed​ on some other place then selenium show errors. If you want to use firefox on any other place then use below code :-

```
File pathToBinary = new File("C:\\user\\Programme\\FirefoxPortable\\App\\Firefox\\firefox.exe");
FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathToBinary);
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();       
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary,firefoxProfile);
```

C:\user\Programme\FirefoxPortable\App\Firefox\firefox.exe--> Replace this path with your path